# A query calls two instances of the same tables joined to compare fields, gives mirrored results. How do I eliminate mirrored duplicates?

Tags: sql, oracle

This is a simpler version of the query I have.

```
Alias1 as 
(select distinct ID, file_tag, status, creation_date from tables where creation_dt >= sysdate and creation_dt <= sysdate + 1),

Alias2 as 
(select distinct ID, file_tag, status, creation_date from same tables creation_dt >= sysdate and creation_dt <= sysdate + 1)

select distinct Alias1.ID ID_1,
           Alias2.ID ID_2,
           Alias1.file_tag,
           Alias1.creation_date in_dt1,
           Alias2.creation_date in_dt2
    from   Alias1, Alias2
    where Alias1.file_tag = Alias2.file_tag
          and Alias1.ID != Alias2.ID
    order by Alias1.creation_dt desc
```

This is an example of the results. Both of these are the same, though their values are flipped.

```
    ID_1 ID_2  File_Tag     in_dt1          in_dt2
    70   66    Apples       6/25/2012 3:06  6/25/2012 2:53:47 PM
    66   70    Apples       6/25/2012 2:53  6/25/2012 3:06:18 PM
```

The goal of the query is to find more than one ID with a matching file tag and do stuff to the one submitted earlier in the day (the query runs daily and only needs duplicates from that given day). I am still relatively new to SQL/Oracle and wonder if there's a better way to approach this problem.

Comment: I'm not sure that I understand what you want, but will replacing `and Alias1.ID != Alias2.ID` with `and Alias1.ID > Alias2.ID` do?

Comment: Do you always have a maximum of two entries for the same tag?

Comment: @Dems: There is a possibility that we can see 3 or more results sharing the same tag, or one, or none.

Comment: @A.B.Cade Sorry, but that won't help. The important fields are the tag and the date. If the tags match, we need to compare the dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an easy way, just by chaning your comparison operation:

```
select distinct Alias1.ID ID_1, Alias2.ID ID_2, Alias1.file_tag,
       Alias1.creation_date in_dt1, Alias2.creation_date in_dt2
from Alias1 join
     Alias2
     on Alias1.file_tag = Alias2.file_tag and
        Alias1.ID < Alias2.ID
order by Alias1.creation_dt desc
```

Replacing the not-equals with less-than orders the two ideas so the smaller one is always first.  This will eliminate the duplicates.  Note:  I also fixed the join syntax.

Comment: Thanks, this does what I need, though  will have to test it further.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT id, file_tag, creation_date in_dt
             , row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY file_tag 
                                      ORDER BY creation_date) rn
             , count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY file_tag) ct
          FROM tables
         WHERE creation_date >= TRUNC(SYSDATE)) tbls
 WHERE rn = 1
   AND ct > 1;
```

This should get you the first (earliest) row within each file_tag having at least 2 records today.

The inner select calculates the relative row numbers of each set of identical file_tag records by creation date. The outer select retrieves the first one in each partition.

This assumes from your goal statement that you want to do something with the earliest single row for each file_tag. The inner query only returns rows with a creation_date of sometime on the current day.

Comment: Wouldn't you want a `count(*) over ( partition by file_tag )` in there as well to ensure that there's at least two?

Comment: I will edit the question above, but this will be something that runs daily and only looks at results for the given day. I omitted it for clarity, but part of the final query also selects where in_dt <= sysdate + 1 and in_dt >= sysdate.

Comment: This was helpful, but it returned all unique results, regardless of duplicates, and returned the more recent entries instead of the ones posted earlier in the day. The other answer returns the earliest results of just the duplicates for the day.

Comment: @BrettH if you `ORDER BY creation_date desc` it'll return the ones from earlier in the day and the `count(*)` in there now should ensure that at there is a duplicate.